# Bootstrap 4 how to put label and input field in horizontal

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am designing a form in Bootstrap 4,there are few requirements I need to fulfill:

1)The screen should be divided to two part.(The ID&Age is one part, Name&College is one part. )
For this to work, I am using `class="container"`, is it correct?

2)The label and input field should be horizontal in Large screen but will be vertical when the screen become medium.
(Now I am only able to let it stay vertical in medium screen but unable to let it become horizontal in large screen.)(I used `class="row"`but it does work.)

My HTML:

```
    <h3 class="title text-center">Student Form</h3>


    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" #studentForm="ngForm">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <label class="col-form-label ">ID:</label>

                <input #SID [(ngModel)]="student.id" formControlName="ID" type="number"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 ">
                <label class="col-form-label">Name:</label>

                <input #SName [(ngModel)]="student.name" formControlName="name" type="text"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm" />

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <label class="  ">Age:</label>

            <input #SAge [(ngModel)]="student.age" formControlName="age" type="number"
              class="form-control form-control-sm" />
          </div>


          <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <label class="col-form-label ">College:</label>

            <select #SCollege class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="college" [(ngModel)]="student.college">
              <option value="Harvard">Harvard</option>
              <option value="INTI">INTI</option>
              <option value="Sunway">Sunway</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[[image][This is the form in large screen]

[[image]][This is the form in medium screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is in bootstrap official doc , https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add class `class="form-inline"` inside form tag.